# How can I reverse parts of sentence in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a sentence, let's say:

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

I want to create a function that takes 2 arguments, a sentence and a list of things to ignore. And it returns that sentence with the reversed words, however it should ignore the stuff I pass to it in a second argument. This is what I have at the moment:

```
def main(sentence, ignores):
    return ' '.join(word[::-1] if word not in ignores else word for word in sentence.split())
```

But this will only work if I pass a second list like so:

```
print(main('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', ['quick', 'lazy']))
```

However, I want to pass a list like this:

```
print(main('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', ['quick brown', 'lazy dog']))
```

expected result:
`ehT quick brown xof spmuj revo eht lazy dog`

So basically the second argument (the list) will have parts of the sentence that should be ignored. Not just single words.

Do I have to use regexp for this? I was trying to avoid it...

Comment: Are you ignoring the words or the full phrase?

Comment: I'm trying to ignore full phrases.

Comment: So if brown appeared later it not after quick it should be reversed?

Comment: if there's just 'brown' then it should be reversed. 'quick brown' should not be reversed..

Comment: So it's almost like creating temporary placeholders for these ignores. Maybe I should do that? Just create `{}` these in text by using `replace` and then do `format(ignores)` afterwards.

Comment: Actually nevermind, that wouldn't work I just realised.

Comment: @Bravi I thing it is good idea. Put some marks (single words) instead of ignored sentences, reverse all words except marks and put ignored sentences instead of marks.

Comment: What about overlapping matches and substring matches? i.e `main('quick brown dogs jumps over the lazy dog', ['quick brown', 'brown dog'])`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placeholders, why not just initially reverse any phrase that you want to be around the right way, then reverse the whole string:

```
def main(sentence, ignores):
    for phrase in ignores:
        reversed_phrase = ' '.join([word[::-1] for word in phrase.split()])
        sentence = sentence.replace(phrase, reversed_phrase)

    return ' '.join(word[::-1] for word in sentence.split())

print(main('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', ['quick', 'lazy']))
print(main('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', ['quick brown', 'lazy dog']))
```

returns:

```
ehT quick nworb xof spmuj revo eht lazy god
ehT quick brown xof spmuj revo eht lazy dog
```

Comment: what if you have `['lazy dog', 'quick brown']` ?

Comment: This isn't a bad idea, but it does require that the `list` of phrases to leave unchanged match the sentence structure in both number of repetitions (can't ignore all instances of a phrase, just one at a time) and order (`ignores` must match order seen in sentence exactly).

Comment: i'm thinking that you could first search for the index that that each phrase is found in the sentence, then sort ignores by that index and then do the replace's.

Comment: @SuperShoot: That still assumes no duplicate phrases.

Comment: Yes you are right. Maybe there is a solution using keyword placeholders so that the `.format()` replaces all instances and order doesn't matter. Getting a little convoluted though.

Comment: See updated answer. I think if you initially reverse all of the phrases that you want around the right way, then reverse the whole string it should work yeh?

Comment: I like this idea actually. I think it's more readable as well than others.

Comment: Thanks @Bravi. However, this won't behave correctly if the ignore phrases overlap e.g. `['quick brown', 'brown fox']` as mentioned by @Padraic Cunningham.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the first person to recommend avoiding regular expressions, but in this case, the complexity of doing without is greater than the complexity added by using them:

```
import re

def main(sentence, ignores):
    # Dedup and allow fast lookup for determining whether to reverse a component
    ignores = frozenset(ignores)

    # Make a pattern that will prefer matching the ignore phrases, but
    # otherwise matches each space and non-space run (so nothing is dropped)
    # Alternations match the first pattern by preference, so you'll match
    # the ignores phrases if possible, and general space/non-space patterns
    # otherwise
    pat = r'|'.join(map(re.escape, ignores)) + r'|\S+|\s+'

    # Returns the chopped up pieces (space and non-space runs, but ignore phrases stay together
    parts = re.findall(pat, sentence)

    # Reverse everything not found in ignores and then put it all back together
    return ''.join(p if p in ignores else p[::-1] for p in parts)
```

Comment: Why `frozenset` instead of just `set`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Absolutely no reason except that we won't be modifying it later. In practice, I don't think it makes a difference (current versions of Python perform no special optimizations for `frozenset`; the internal structures for `set` and `frozenset` are identical, so if you never mutate it, the only difference is suitability for use as a `dict` key or `set` member), but I use `frozenset` when it's not intended to be mutated; costs nothing to do so, can always be changed if needed. If phrases might be subphrases of each other, you'd want `collections.OrderedDict` to preserve order.

Answer (score 0):

Just another idea, reverse every word and then reverse the ignores right back:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> def main(sentence, ignores):
        def r(s):
            return ' '.join(w[::-1] for w in s.split())
        return reduce(lambda s, i: s.replace(r(i), i), ignores, r(sentence))

>>> main('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', ['quick brown', 'lazy dog'])
'ehT quick brown xof spmuj revo eht lazy dog'
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You underestimate me. How about for example renaming `r` and all its variables to `_`? That is, `def _(_): return ' '.join(_[::-1] for _ in _.split())`?

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted to solve the issue of overlapping ignore phrases e.g. `['brown fox', 'quick brown']` raised by @PadraicCunningham.

There's obviously a lot more looping and code feels less pythonic so I'd be interested in feedback on how to improve this.

```
import re

def _span_combiner(spans):
    """replace overlapping spans with encompasing single span"""
    for i, s in enumerate(spans):
        start = s[0]
        end = s[1]
        for x in spans[i:]:
            if x[0] < end:
                end = x[1]
        yield (start, end) 

def main(sentence, ignores):
    # spans is a start and finish indices for each ignore phrase in order of occurence
    spans = sorted(
            [[m.span() for m in re.finditer(p, sentence)][0] for p in ignores if p in sentence]
    )
    # replace overlapping indices with single set of indices encompasing overlapped range
    spans = [s for s in _span_combiner(spans)]
    # recreate ignore list by slicing sentence with combined spans
    ignores = [sentence[s[0]:s[1]] for s in spans]
    for phrase in ignores:
        reversed_phrase = ' '.join([word[::-1] for word in phrase.split()])
        sentence = sentence.replace(phrase, reversed_phrase)

    return ' '.join(word[::-1] for word in sentence.split())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(main('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', ['quick', 'lazy']))
    print(main('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', ['brown fox', 'lazy dog']))
    print(main('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', ['nonexistent' ,'brown fox', 'quick brown']))
    print(main('The quick brown fox jumps over the brown fox', ['brown fox', 'quick brown']))
```

results:

```
ehT quick nworb xof spmuj revo eht lazy god
ehT kciuq brown fox spmuj revo eht lazy dog
ehT quick brown fox spmuj revo eht yzal god
ehT quick brown fox spmuj revo eht brown fox
```